# SQL Where IN CLAUSE Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ssms

I have a process where I basically have to go through a spreadsheet and look up individuals name by name on an internal system by name/surname and DOB and then retrieve the setting in what they attend.

I have been given access to the database and I have previous experience with SQL but nothing extensive. I have put dummy names for my tables as below just because it can contain sensitive information.

I want to know if there is anyway I can do this in an easier way, I will eventually be connecting to the db via VBA and retrieving the data this way. I don't know if I could insert a variable into the IN Clause and create a custom function which create a variable which will return something like 'Bob','Keith' etc  it so it can be passed into SQL (hopefully that makes sense). Also, are you able to pass abbreviated table names if you are passing the SQL through VBA?

Also I am not sure if it is possible so that the setting is returned on the correct rows or its best to use some lookup function on multiple criteria?

It isn't a great way of doing things I know but its the only way as each person doesnt have a unique identifier in the data I initially receive.

```
SELECT  p.Forename
      ,p.Surname
      ,p.Birth_Date
      ,p.xxx
      ,p.xxx
      ,csc.name
      ,cs.name2 
FROM dbo.Person AS P
INNER JOIN dbo.banana AS csc ON csc.xxx = p.xxx
INNER JOIN dbo.apple AS cs ON cs.xxx = p.xxx
WHERE p.forename IN('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
  AND p.surname IN('xx','xx','xx', 'xx')
  AND p.Birth_Date IN(N'xx', N'xxx', N'xxx', N'xxx')
```

Comment: you can pass a variable of type array if you are running this query from any program.

Comment: Do you store dates in a nvarchar column?

Comment: The canonical way to do this is with a TVP, but old fashioned ADO driver used in VBA does not support it. Maybe a CSV and then split it with `STRING_SPLIT`?

Comment: Hi @jarlh dates are as dates, I guess it doesnt need to be in apostrophes?

Comment: No, it doesn't need the notational character (`N`) @paulr23. `N'xx'` *implies* your column `Birth_Date` is an `nvarchar`, as you're passing `nvarchar` literals to it; which you would only do with an `nvarchar`. Dates, when using strings, are best served as `varchar` values in the format `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` but *really* you should be passing them as a date and time data type (though impossible if you do need to go down the `STRING_SPLIT` method).

Comment: @Larnu Hi, it doesnt work unless I pass N as the dates are 2020-01-01 it doesnt like the - I checked the table properties and the birthdate is a date

Comment: *"it doesnt work unless I pass N as the dates"* to a date and time data type, `N'2020-01-01'` and `'2020-01-01'` are identical; neither contain a character outside of the normal code pages and they would both be implicitly converted to the appropriate date and time data type. If it doesn't work when you pass `'2020-01-01'`, but does when you pass `N'2020-01-01'`, then there's something *very* wrong with your data.

Comment: @Larnu sorry I am wrong it works without the N'infront, I didnt really know what this is but it works without it anyway so all good. Still need an idea to come up with however

Comment: To use a variable with the in clause implies dynamic sql, which you shouldnt do in this scenario. I would work with the dba/sql dev team to see if creating a stored procedure for you to pass in those variables and let them handle it on their end. I would even suggest you just send a json object.

Comment: @DougCoats how come you shouldnt do it this way, performance?

Comment: @paulr23 Just imagine all the end user like yourselves sending in dynamic sql doing god knows what without any way to protect the database from malicious behavior.

Comment: Also, the way your query is structured it implies that all values with name in (...) and DOB in (...) will be returned. Youre literally going to get every combo because theres no way to tie them together the way you wrote it. A json object would o that for you.

Comment: Yea I have no idea what that really is. It would only be one person doing this on a daily basis with a recordset of circa <50 records

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the control and access you have, you could use XML to pass in a list of values.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
DECLARE
    @forenames xml = '<names><name>Bill</name><name>Steven</name><name>Steve</name></names>',
    @surnames xml = '<names><name>Gates</name><name>Spielberg</name><name>Jobs</name></names>',
    @birthdates xml = '<dates><date>10/28/1955</date><date>12/18/1946</date><date>02/24/1955</date></dates>';

SELECT 
    p.Forename
    , p.Surname
    , p.Birth_Date
    , p.xxx
    , p.xxx
    , csc.name
    , cs.name2 
FROM dbo.Person AS P
INNER JOIN dbo.banana AS csc ON csc.xxx = p.xxx
INNER JOIN dbo.apple AS cs ON cs.xxx = p.xxx
WHERE 
    p.forename IN(
        SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'varchar(50)' ) FROM @forenames.nodes( '//names/name' ) x( f )
    )
    AND p.surname IN(
        SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'varchar(50)' ) FROM @surnames.nodes( '//names/name' ) x( f )
    )
    AND p.Birth_Date IN(
        SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'varchar(50)' ) FROM @birthdates.nodes( '//dates/date' ) x( f )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, could you explain at all at what this really is as I do not understand it too well. And how i pass the values into xml would this be manually?

Comment: This allows you to pass a list of values via a string in XML that can be used with `IN`.